# Could I integrate Firebase in my app using jcenter() instead of mavenCentral() in project build.gradle?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, gradle

I am trying to imlement firebase in my app and I have followed the steps of their web. The problem is that I have seen one step that it is said to ause mavenCentral but the problem is that I am using jcenter.

This is what it is said in the Firebase web to use in the project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

  }
}

allprojects {
  ...
  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

  }
}
```

In my project build.gradle I have the following code (I am using jcenter() as I have some libraries from jcenter) :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

So, if I have my build.gradle with jcenter(), will it be working for Firebase integration although mavenCentral has been replaced for jcenter or it is strictly necessary to use mavenCentral().

Comment: repository are not necessary to use it only depends on where the library you are using are hosted .. R u getting any build error ?

Comment: @ADM so it doesn´t matter if I use jcenter() or mavenCentral()? So if it doesn´t matter, why in the firebase guide to implement it, in the code I can see only to add mavenCentral and not jcenter? I have perceived it as strictly necessary to use mavenCentral in the guide...